# openjdk-11-jre-headless installation problem on ubuntu 18.4

Tags: java, linux, bash, ubuntu-18.04, java-11

**I am trying to install openjdk-11-jre-headless or default-jre on my ubuntu machine but no mather what I do I get some error messages while doing it.**

```
" The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-11-jre-headless : Depends: initscripts but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages " 

" The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre : Depends: default-jre-headless (= 2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: openjdk-11-jre but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. "
```

**I have tried these commands to fix the problem but no luck..**

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
dpkg reconfigure -a
```

**I tried the same thing with aptitude: aptitude install default-jre but no luck...**

Any ideas how to fix the " broken package " and dependency issuses?

Detailed system information

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Comment: Hello ! Your question is not about programming, and might be considered out of scope for the site. Sites like SuperUser or AskUbuntu should be more suited for this kind of question

Comment: Also, quick suggestion : have you tried `apt-get install -f` ?

Comment: Hello yes. I tried to post it in the askubuntu site but didn't manage to post.

Comment: Also apt-get install -f did nothing.

Comment: Try it here: https://askubuntu.com/